# ArcGIS Pro - Layers Show in Contents but not on Map

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, sentinel-1, image-analyst

I am new to ArcGIS Pro. I came across a short [course](https://learn.arcgis.com/en/projects/process-sentinel-1-sar-data/) from Esri learning about the processing of Sentinel data. They taught several techniques about how to mitigating speckle, removing radiometric and geometric distortions by using ArcGIS Image Analyst toolbox. The problem I am facing is when I am doing certain processing like removing thermal noise, a new layer is added in the content pane but it is not visible in the map layer. This happens for every processing tool in "Image Analyst" toolbox giving the same output. I tried clearing cache, temp folder, saving it as a new project. building everything new, but this problem is still occurring. I even went to the sci-hub Copernicus to download new Sentinel 1 data. But same problem is still happening. I am using ArcGIS Pro 3.0.1 version.

[image]

Comment: Did you look at the layers order, try to drag and drop them from bottom to top.

Comment: What is the coordinate reference system of IW_manifest and what was your despeckle tolerance? It's possible that you've despeckled to one pixel or less. How many rows/columns does IW_manifest_Dspk have? If the CRS hasn't been duplicated from your source to result it could also be outside the map area, try zooming to the layer.

Comment: Double check your projections - are the images not showing up at all, or are they just not showing up where you expect them to be?

Answer (score -1):

If you are experiencing the "Layers Show in Contents but not on Map" issue in ArcGIS Pro, double-check the settings and the visibility options.

Comment: Which settings do you mean?